# 10 checkboxes and labels - want 5 on the left 5 on the right with remaining space below

Tags: html, css, angularjs

So I have 10 checkboxes, each label is taken from a corresponding index in an array.  I'm using ng-repeat to show them :

```
<div ng-repeat="entity in entityArray | filter:entity">

        <label>
          <input style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 5px" type="checkbox" ng-model="entityChecked" ng-change="getEntityFromModal(entity, entityChecked)" />
                <a>{{entity}}</a>
        </label>
</div>
```

How can I display 5 on the left and 5 on the right?  Preferably I'd rather a solution which used only one array and one div.

Comment: Depending on which [browser versions](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) you have to support, I'd go with [CSS FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't want to use any more divs you could use something like:

```
label:nth-child(-n+5) {
    float: left;
}

input:nth-child(n+6) {
    float: right 
}
```

Which will float the first 5 left, and any after that will be floated to the right.

However I would recommend wrapping the first 5 in a div with text-align: left and the other 5 in a div with text-align: right then setting both divs to 50% width. But this is only because I dissaprove of the use of floats.

**Edit**
To clarify this answer will result in something like

```
[][][][][]            [][][][][]
```

And not

```
[]     []
[]     []
[]     []
[]     []
[]     []
```

To achieve this then we can modify the code slightly and use

```
label:nth-child(2n):after {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    content : "";
}
```

Comment: I understand, the issue then is I would need two array's holding my label's values (which are routinely changed, via the code), and two separate ng-repeats one for each div?  Would you still recommend not using floats in your way described?

Comment: My recommendation against float is based on people using it everywhere without reason. As you actually have a legitimate reason IE. it would involve changes in logic without, I think float will be fine.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with this solution (how great is it to have a choice, thanks everyone) since it maintains my javascript structure, which is important as in the future it may be changed so the UI will have an entity input.  However within my page I have multiple inputs, and this is formatting all of them?

Comment: Yes it will do, you will need to add a class to the parent div (the div with ng-repear), and then use .newClassName label:nth-child(-n+....

Comment: Ah excellent, thanks @samuelmr ,as you've probably guessed my css is very basic.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the ordering being

```
1 2
3 4
4 5
...
```

rather than

```
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10
```

you can simply do:

```css
.container {
    width: 500px;
}
.cb {
    float: left;
    
    width: 48%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div classs="container">
    <label class="cb">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <a>entity name</a>
    </label>
    <label class="cb">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <a>entity name</a>
    </label>
    <label class="cb">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <a>entity name</a>
    </label>
    <label class="cb">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <a>entity name</a>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd still go with Flex.

```css
.container {
    width: 500px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.cb {
    align-self:auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <label class="cb">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <a>entity name 1</a>
    </label>
    <label class="cb">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <a>entity name 2</a>
    </label>
    <label class="cb">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <a>entity name 3</a>
    </label>
    <label class="cb">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <a>entity name 4</a>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Support for flex isn't great and you don't have to use it to accomplish this

Comment: It depends on which browser versions he has to support. It's an easy, clean and highly responsive solution, if supported. See [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex),